# A biopython script to split a large fasta file into multiple ones

Tags: python, biopython

I am working on a large fasta file I want to spliting into multiple ones according to the gene id. I am trying to use the above script from biopython tutorials:

```
def batch_iterator(iterator, batch_size):
    """Returns lists of length batch_size.

    This can be used on any iterator, for example to batch up
    SeqRecord objects from Bio.SeqIO.parse(...), or to batch
    Alignment objects from Bio.AlignIO.parse(...), or simply
    lines from a file handle.

    This is a generator function, and it returns lists of the
    entries from the supplied iterator.  Each list will have
    batch_size entries, although the final list may be shorter.
    """
    entry = True  # Make sure we loop once
    while entry:
        batch = []
        while len(batch) < batch_size:
            try:
                entry = iterator.next()
            except StopIteration:
                entry = None
            if entry is None:
                # End of file
                break
            batch.append(entry)
        if batch:
            yield batch 

record_iter=SeqIO.parse(open('/path/sorted_sequences.fa'), 'fasta')
for i, batch in enumerate (batch_iterator(record_iter, 93)):
    filename='gene_%i.fasta' % (i + 1)
    with open('/path/files/' + filename, 'w') as ouput_handle:
        count=SeqIO.write(batch, ouput_handle, 'fasta')
    print ('Wrote %i records to %s' % (count, filename))
```

It does split the files with 93 sequence in them but it gives 2 files per group of 93. I cannot see the error but I guess there is one. 
There is another way I could split the large fasta file in a different way?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `it gives 2 files per group of 93?'

Comment: That the script produces duplicate files i.e 2 files of 93 genes each with gene_1. And I know that there is 93 of each. So after producing the first 93 sequence file, should move to the next 93 but i doesn't do it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there is anyone interested in this script in the future. The script works perfectly the way it is. The problems was that the file I was trying to divide had more sequences than it should. So I deleted the bad file, and produce a new one that split nicely with the above script.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the code in the example, the iterator does not seem to separate files per **gene id** but just make a divition of the sequences in groups of `batch_size`, so in your case 93 sequences per file.

Comment: That is what I thought. But being a newbie in this I thought that as each gene has a sequence it will separate them accordingly. The file is sorted in the way that the first 93 sequences correspond to gene_1, and the next 93 to another gene.id and so on. Is there anyway I can seraparate them the way I would like to? Thanks

Comment: @Ana You can, there are several ways to do it not only one.  It will depend if you already know all the names of the genes or if you need to fetch them first. Then you can parse the file as many times as the number of different genes you have (slow process) or you can think of a more clever way. I advice you to try to do it and if you are blocked, post a question here or in biostars with the code you tried and the error or blockage you have.

Comment: I know the name of the genes as I modified them before. I guess that there is many way to do it but I am not much literate in file handling with python.